# using sed command to give variables with echo

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

We are trying to use the sed command to give back contents from 2 files (file1q and file1a) -  a question and answer file.

The question and answer file are the same with numbers on each line:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

We are trying to echo the result however the sed command is being echo'd and not the result from the sed command

This is our code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#clear screen
clear

#reset score to 0
score=0

#loop over files to find contents
i=1
while [ $i -le 10 ]
do

question="sed -n $i{p} file1q.txt"
answer="sed -n $i{p} file1a.txt"

if [ question == answer ]
then
    echo "Correct"
else
    echo "incorrect"
fi

i=$(( $i + 1 ))

done
```

As you can see i = 1 so sed should be printing line 1 from both files...
However, this is what we are getting (using double quotes):
[output with double quotes for echo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhqL9.png)

this is what we are getting with single quotes:
[output with single quotes for echo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfa3F.png)

this is what we want:

[output without echo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY7wW.png)

Comment: `if [[ $question = $answer ]]`

Comment: thanks for the input bac0n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign to the `question` and `answer` variables command strings, not output of the commands. It looks like you want this:

```
question=$(sed -n $i{p} file1q.txt)
answer=$(sed -n $i{p} file1a.txt)
```

This will run `sed` commands and assign output to the vars.

Comment: thank you . this is what we was after